# 4+1 architectural view model - example for web application

Tags: architecture, viewmodel

could anyone suggest me an example of 4+1 model of some web application? I am not sure, how it should look like.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Here, let me google this for you:  https://www.google.com/search?q=4%2B1%20architecture%20sample%20document%20web%20application